# how to trigger ValueChangeListener of vaadin combobox within program

Tags: java, combobox, vaadin, valuechangelistener

How can I trigger the ValueChangeListener of vaadin combobox within program.
I have a combobox with 5 values and what if I set the value to one of them, with in the program, then I want to trigger the ValueChangeListener

```
    String statusFilterValue = STATUS_FILTER_DEFAULT;
    if (statusFilterComboBox.isEmpty())
    {
        statusFilterComboBox.addItem(STATUS_FILTER_DEFAULT);
        statusFilterComboBox.setNullSelectionAllowed(false);
        statusFilterComboBox.setTextInputAllowed(false);

        statusFilterComboBox.addItem(MY_CONFLICT_FILTER);
        for (ReferenceStatus item : ReferenceStatus.values())
            statusFilterComboBox.addItem(item);
    }
    else
    {
        statusFilterValue = (String) statusFilterComboBox.getValue();
    }
    statusFilterComboBox.setValue(statusFilterValue);
    // This is where I am trying to trigger the event
    statusFilterComboBox.select(statusFilterValue);
   statusFilterComboBox.addValueChangeListener(statusFilterComboBoxListener);
```

Comment: Have you tried first adding the value-change-listener and then setting the value, instead of the other way around?

Comment: I tried, it didnt work

Comment: Then please provide a [sscce](http://sscce.org) because I made a quick sample and it worked just fine. Also please let us know what Vaadin version you're using.

Comment: As @Morfic says, you have to call first `addValueChangeListener(yourListener)` and after that `setValue(newValue)`. If that does not work, try debugging inside `setValue` it's possible that the ComboBox is dettecting your value as not listed or that it is already selected